# Can't run brand new Xamarin Forms in Live Player

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2017, xamarin-live-player

I created a brand new Xamarin Forms project and made no changes to it whatsoever.

I paired the LivePlayer installed on my iPhone and when I build the solution I get no errors.

However, when I try to debug using LivePlayer, it fails and the only errors I'm seeing in the output are:

> No Address and User has been specified in order to establish a
>   connection to a Mac Server, so only the main assembly was compiled for
>   project 'myMobileApp.iOS'. Connect to a Mac Server and try again to
>   build the full application.

and

> There is no available connection to the Mac, hence the task
>   Xamarin.MacDev.Tasks.CollectBundleResources will not be executed

This is my first experience with Xamarin and not a good experience to start with!

Any idea what's the issue here and how to fix it?

BTW, I'm using Visual Studio 2017 15.6.6 and I'm not seeing any updates.

Comment: The error messages indicate that you didn't set up a connection to your Mac. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/

Comment: And you should have a mac environment as well with XCode installed in that mac environment.

Comment: I thought the whole point of the LivePlayer was to be able to test and debug the app while developing on Windows.

Comment: There are some limitations with Xamarin Forms in Live Player ,refer to 
[here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/tools/live-player/limitations?tabs=ios#limitations-1), and Live Player is not intended to debug app.

Answer (score 0):

the live player is meant more as a fancy mock up rather than a debugging environment.

in xamarin.forms on vs2017: view>other windows>xamarin forms previewer
this will give you visual only mock up

live player is a mix between that and the following

USB connection to PC, debugging on actual device

in absence of real hardware, you can try the emulator

it is advisable to always debug on connected hardware.

if you are not connected to a mac, i suggest going into the configuration manager and turning off ios build (debug and release) until you can connect to a mac.